# issue with minify html with gulp

Tags: html, gulp, minify, gulp-minify

I tried **[gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin)** and some other packages for minify html but can't minify my html files.

[cmd err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5gua.png)

my **package.josn:**

```
{
  "name": "asb-with-gulp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-scss": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-clean-css": "^3.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-concat-js": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-html-minifier": "^0.1.8",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-minifier": "^0.2.2",
    "gulp-sort": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "pump": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Gilas Software Team",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code using `gulp-htmlmin`

Comment: Have you tried adding `type="text/javascript"` attribute to your script tags?

Comment: @İbrahimDuran Yes, my script tag have `type="text/javascript"`